How to connect to MySQL using ODBC and ZeosLib
I use ZeosLib to connect and work with Mysql database. I need to connect via ODBC. I have configured ODBC on the computer and tested the connection which is successful.
When I tried to connect via ZConnection I realized that ZeosLib does not support odbc. In the protocol combobox there is no option to select ODBC.
How do I solve this?

This is my code
procedure TMainConnection.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ZConnection1 do
  begin
    Protocol := 'odbc';
    Database := 'GalenaRadnjaODBCDataSource';
    User := 'root';
    Password := '';

    try
      Connect;  

      if Connected then
        raise Exception.Create('Success');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('Error: ' + E.Message);
      end;

    end;

  end;
end;


This answer explains that Zeos intentionally (and idiologically) won't support ODBC.

If Zeos doesn't support ODBC, then there is no fix to the issue. Not supported is NOT SUPPORTED. The solution if you have to have ODBC support is not to use Zeos, but to use something else instead that does support it.
